# How can I await api results before doing a matchSnapshot test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have a test that does a snapshot match on the DOM. I am not sure if I am using the correct mount/render or correct testing library for this. The issue I am having is when the component is called, it awaits the API result. However, my test is not waiting for the api result even though I have put an act around it. Wondering if I have done something wrong or used incorrect function from the library.

This is what I tried.

```
await act(async () => {
      const { container } = render(<Home />);

      await mockGetMovies;

      expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <div>
        <main>
          <h1>
            Movies (1)
          </h1>
        </main>
      </div>
    `);
    });
```

Snapshot is (actual)

```
 <p>
    Fetching data...
 </p>
```

when it should be (expecting)

```
<main>
   <h1>
      Movies (1)
   </h1>
</main>
```

Here is what the full test code looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { getMovies } from '../app/requests/getMovies';
import Home from '.';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

jest.mock('../app/requests/getMovies');

const mockGetMovies = getMovies as jest.Mock;

describe('/', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockGetMovies.mockResolvedValue([
      {
        Title: 'Titanic',
      },
    ]);
  });

  it('should render the homepage', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      const { container } = render(<Home />);

      await mockGetMovies;

      expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <div>
        <main>
          <h1>
            Movies (1)
          </h1>
        </main>
      </div>
    `);
    });
  });
});
```

Here is what the Component Looks like

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getMovies } from '../app/requests/getMovies';

const Home = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies().then((data) => {
      setMovies(data);
    });
  }, []);

  if (movies.length == 0) {
    return <p>Fetching data...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Movies ({movies.length})</h1>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Replace your await mockGetMovies with -  `await act(() => Promise.resolve());`

Comment: @Shyam that didn't work either. Did you mean I should remove the exiting act too?

Comment: you should not wrap your entire text with act . remove this ` await act(async () => {`

Comment: @coding1223322 Couple of things wrong with your test, in addition to what was already suggested: 1) You don't need to explicitly call `mockGetMovies`, that'll be done by the component you're testing; 2) Wrap your `expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(...)` call with `await waitFor(() => ...)` - that will ensure the async operation inside the component's `useEffect` is completed.